# How to format one word in jTextArea() if it is spelt wrong?

Tags: arrays, swing, formatting, spell-checking, jtextarea

I am making a text editor and the last step is to create a simple spell checker. I have managed to work out how find incorrect words but now I would like to format those words so that they are shown to be incorrect example underlining them or highlighting them.

How can you format one word in a jtextarea() differently to the rest?

```
public void Spell_Check()
    {

    String[] english = new String[26871];
    String[] text_words = ((JTextArea) TabPane.getSelectedComponent()).getText().split(" "); 

     int count_words = 0;
     try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("english.txt"));


        String lineFromFile = "";


       for(int i = 0; (lineFromFile = br.readLine()) != null; i++)
       {
         if(text_words[i] != lineFromFile )
         {

          text_words[i].setAttributes(51,  7, false);   
         }
       }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at question [Delayed text color change in Swing text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803658/textfield-text-color-change-in-java-swing) where an answer is given on how to achieve this in a `JTextField`. And since the answer uses methods available on `JTextComponent` you can uses this for a `JTextArea` as well.

An even better example would be the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), and more specifically the [`TextFieldDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextFieldDemoProject/src/components/TextFieldDemo.java) which does almost exactly what you want